# Should an adjective or adverb be used? "writing this haphazard"

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I am reading EB White's letters and encountered the following sentence:

> I'm just writing this **haphazard** for no reason other than that I felt like awriting you a letter before going to bed.

I am wondering if he should have used *haphazard* or *haphazardly* in the above sentence. Why?

Comment: It could also  be a deliberate play on words. (In that he knew he should have used *haphazardly* but misused the adjective deliberately. The fact that it's ungrammatical is its own best demonstration of how haphazardly he was writing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may just be a mistake — this is a personal letter, written with haste and emotion, so it may not have been carefully edited.

But E. B. White was well-read, so he was probably using *haphazard* in the old way: [before it was an adjective](https://www.etymonline.com/word/haphazard), it was [a noun meaning "chance, accident"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haphazard). So he's calling his letter a haphazard, i.e. saying it was unplanned.

This usage is archaic now, and even native speakers no longer recognize it.

(Is "awriting" in the original, or is that a typo?)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'haphazard' is an adjective, so it is supposed to modify noun after it.
But I think the writer means "I'm just writing this haphazard **thing** for no reason"
without mentioning the word **'thing'.**

And yes, if you use haphazardly there, it will be correct as haphazardly is an adverb that will modify the action verb 'writing'.

Hope my opinion helps!